# How to redirect user to another page using getServerSideProps?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js

I found this solution:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ res }) => {
  res.redirect(301, '/another-page')
  
  return {
    props: {}
  }
}
```

but I don't see `redirect` method in the `res` and get an error

Comment: Are you calling this conditionally and this is just _pseudo-code_? if you want to do it every time a reverse proxy or a CDN redirect maybe better to avoid hitting next js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're using Next.js.
Try something like this.

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ res }) => {
  res.setHeader("location", "/another-page")
  res.statusCode = 301
  res.end()
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner approach would be look like this:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ res }) => {
  res.writeHead(302, { Location: '//another-page/' });
  res.end()
  return;
}
```

I would suggest you to use Status code 302 instead of 301

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why 302 instead of 301?

Comment: A 301 redirect means that the page has permanently moved to a new location. A 302 redirect means that the move is only temporary. Search engines need to figure out whether to keep the old page, or replace it with the one found at the new location.